# Deleting multiple rows using checkboxes in Struts2

Tags: java, checkbox, struts2, delete-row

I display rows in an HTML table with a checkbox in a column in each row of the table something like the following.

```
<s:iterator value="objects" status="loopStatus">

    <td>
        <s:label for="%{id}" value="%{#loopStatus.index+1}"/>
        <s:checkbox id="%{id}" name="chk" fieldValue="%{id}" value="false"/>
    </td>

    <!--Other columns-->

</s:iterator>
```

`objects` is is a list of objects of a JPA entity, `List<Entity>` initialized in an action class. `id` is a  value of type `Long` that corresponds to a primary key column in the database.

---

The values of these checkboxes are set to its corresponding property in an action class, when the form is submitted.

```
private List<Long>chk;

//setters & getters.
```

The values of selected checkboxes are correctly set to this property `chk`. This list of values is then used to delete rows from the database.

---

This works just fine. A problem occurs, when there is only one row in the table. In which case, an unnecessary conversion error occurs, while performing operations other than deletion (like updating/inserting a row) which requires this checkbox to be selected which is quite unnecessary and should happen only while performing deletion.

> Invalid field value for field "chk".

If I deliberately add an extra checkbox with the same name `chk` then, this conversion error disappears.

Presumably it appears that a single checkbox is not correctly mapped to a list of values of type `Long`, `List<Long>`.

What is the way to get rid of this error, when there is only a single row to be displayed in an HTML table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't check a single checkbox it value by default is set to `false`. You can set the default in `checkbox` interceptor `uncheckedValue` property.

Additionally you may consider to add hidden field so that `checkbox` interceptor will think there are multiple chekboxes when there is only one and won't add default value.

For your checkbox the hidden field name will be `__checkbox_chk`.

```
<s:hidden name="__checkbox_chk"/>
```

Comment: A hidden field like `<input type="hidden" id="__checkbox_23" name="__checkbox_chk" value="23">` is already added to each checkbox so why is this additional hidden field needed? This works fine. Thanks.

Comment: @Tiny: Adding additional hidden field makes interceptor think that there more than one checkbox and default value isn't being set.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one which explicitly cites the array index:

```
<s:iterator value="objects" status="loopStatus">

    <td>
        <s:label for="%{id}" value="%{#loopStatus.index+1}"/>
        <s:checkbox id="%{id}" name="chk[%{#loopStatus.count}]" fieldValue="%{id}" value="false"/>
    </td>

    <!--Other columns-->

</s:iterator>
```

Comment: I have tried with `name="chk[%{#loopStatus.count}]"` and just `name="chk[]"`. The error in question disappeared but in both the cases, the values of the selected checkboxes were not set to the list while deleting rows disallowing deletion of rows. I have also tried to turn `List<Long>chk` to `Long chk[]` but that did not make a difference either.